# Hiding a div if another contains a specific string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, contains

I want to check if an element on page contains a text phrase, it shows a second hidden container? For example, '#product-description' contains 'best gift' then a hidden container '#best-gift-graphic' over the product image is shown. I've found answers that skirt around this, and tackle parts, but I can't seem to put it all together.

I've found solutions that hide the element that contains the text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("div p:contains('text')").parent('div').hide();
 });
</script>
```

I need to apply the show/hide to a second container, not the container with the target phrase in. Really new to jquery and just want to understand the syntax. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Please post a copy of the HTML you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length to see if any items exist, you can then use `.hide()` to hide your corresponding element if there is any:

```js
if ($('#product-description:contains("best gift")').length) { // check if this exists
  $('#best-gift-graphic').hide(); // hide this
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product-description">best gift</div>
<div id="best-gift-graphic">this is hidden</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Got it working a treat. Many thanks for your help Pete. Much appreciated, got me out of a spot.